# Moving columns down and replicating keys in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

`ID       first   mes1.1   mes 1.2  ... mes 1.10   mes2.[1-10]      mes3.[1-10] 
123df   John      5.5      130           45       [12,312,...]    [123,346,53]
...`

where I have abbreviated columns using `[]` notation. So in this dataframe I have 31 columns: `first`, `mes1.[1-10]`, `mes2.[1-10]`, and `mes3.[1-10]`. Each row is keyed by a unique index: `ID`.

I would like to form a new table where I've replicated all column values, (represented here by `ID` and `first`) and move the `mes2` and `mes3` columns (20 of them) "down" giving me something like this:

`ID       first     mes1    mes2  ...     mes10
123df   John      5.5      130           45
123df   John      341      543           53 
123df   John      123      560           567
...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# How I set up your dataframe (please include a reproducible df next time)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6,31), index=["ID" + str(i) for i in range(6)], 
columns=['first'] + ['mes{0}.{1}'.format(i, j) for i in range(1,4) for j in range(1,11)])
df['first'] = 'john'
```

Then there are two ways to do this

```
# Generate new underlying array
first = np.repeat(df['first'].values, 3)[:, np.newaxis]
new_vals = df.values[:, 1:].reshape(18,10)
new_vals = np.hstack((first, new_vals))
# Create new df
m = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((df.index, range(1,4)), names=['ID', 'MesNum'])
pd.DataFrame(new_vals, index=m, columns=['first'] + list(range(1,11)))
```

or using only Pandas

```
df.columns = ['first'] + list(range(1,11))*3
pieces = [df.iloc[:, i:i+10] for i in range(1,31, 10)]
df2 = pd.concat(pieces, keys = ['first', 'second', 'third'])
df2 = df2.swaplevel(1,0).sortlevel(0)
df2.insert(0, 'first', df['first'].repeat(3).values)
```